# An exercise on series of function convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^x}{n^2 \ln n}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am asked to show the various tipes of convergence of this series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^x}{n^2 \ln n}$$ where $x \in R$.

I notice that for  $x \ge 1$ the series diverges because $ \frac{n}{n^2 \ln n} < \frac{n+1}{n^2 \ln n}$ and $\frac{1}{n \ln n}$ diverges from the integral test.

Anyone mind helping me with $x < 1$? I tried root and ratio test.

Comment: Isn´t it supposed to be from n=2 or something since ln(1)=0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x<1$, we have, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{(n+1)^x}{n^2 \ln n}=\frac{n^x(1+1/n)^x}{n^2 \ln n} \sim \frac{1}{n^{2-x} \ln n}
$$

then by applying for example the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to the latter series you conclude that your initial series is **convergent**.

---

*Edit*. *One may observe that*

- if $0\leq x<1$, then as $n \to \infty$,  $$ \frac{1}{n^{2-x} \ln n} \leq
     \frac{(n+1)^x}{n^2 \ln n}=\frac{n^x(1+1/n)^x}{n^2 \ln n} \leq
     \frac{e^x}{n^{2-x} \ln n} $$
- if $x<0$, then as $n \to \infty$,$$ 0<   
     \frac{(n+1)^x}{n^2 \ln n}=\frac{1}{n^2(n+1)^{|x|} \ln n} \leq   
     \frac1{n^2 \ln n} $$

*both cases giving the announced convergence.*

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for the answer, I see that you have all used the asymptotically similar symbol $\sim$, how could I construct the argument to not use the symbol $\sim$?

Comment: @Monolite Ok, let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start the summation from $n=2$, because $\ln 1=0$ (just to be precise). Now, to the point, for $x<1$ $$\frac{(n+1)^x}{n^2\ln n}\sim_{\infty}\frac{n^x}{n^{2}\ln n}=\frac{1}{n^{2-x} \ln n}<\frac{1}{n^a}$$ with $a>1$ which converges.

Comment: Great minds think together ;o)

Comment: @Bernard You win by 1 second I think, so I do not qualify... as of thinking together :(.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a series with positive terms, you can use *equivalents*:
$$\frac{(n+1)^x}{n^2\log n}\sim_\infty\frac{n^x}{n^2\log n}=\frac{1}{n^{2-x}\log n}. $$
This is a *Bertrand's series*, i. e. of type $\dfrac1{n^a\log^bn}$ and it is known to converge if and only $a>1$ or ($a=1$ et $b>1$) (the latter case is proved with the *integral test*).

Thus, in the present case, the series converges if and only if $2-x>1$, i.e. $x<1$.

If you're not allowed to use equivalence, you may adapt the idea behind equivalence as follows:
$$\frac{(n+1)^x}{n^2\log n}=\Bigl(1+\frac1n\Bigr)^x\frac{1}{n^{2-x}\log n}<2^x\frac{1}{n^{2-x}\log n},$$
which is proportional to a Bertrand's series &c.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, how would I formalize the $\sim_\infty$ , my professor does not let us use that.

Comment: I've added a workaround to my answer. But equivalence often makes life simpler…

Comment: Thanks for the very clear answer would I also be right in saying that it converges uniformly on any interval $[ - \infty, c]$ where $c < 1$ ? I say this because on those intervals the series converges totally correct?

Comment: You're quite right, since $2^c\dfrac1{n^{2-c}\log n}$ is an upper bound, independent of $x$.